# Windows command line dates

Tags: windows, cmd

I have an hard coded windows command line with dates (from: yesterday until today) 
I want to replace the hard coded dates with an expression like date.add(-1) for yesterday.
I know how to get current date:  %date:~10,4%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%
but how can I do this for yesterday?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do exactly that in cmd using PowerShell. PowerShell is available for Windows from Windows 7. Are you running Windows 98 or something earlier?

```
FOR /F %a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"') do (SET "YD=%a")
ECHO %YD%
```

Here is a .bat file equivalent.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%a IN ('powershell -NoProfile -Command "(Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')"') do (SET "YD=%%a")
ECHO %YD%
EXIT /B 0
```

Comment: The commands gives is for the Windows cmd.exe. Have you tried it? If you put it in a .bat file, change %a to %%a.

Comment: if you really want to do it in plain batch (which really is a pain), use our [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+get+yesterdays+date).